# getImageList MIGX вывод слайдера

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

Не подскажите почему на главной выводит слайдер через migx а на другой страницу не выводит

```
[[getImageList?
              &tvname=`sliderIm`
              &tpl=`slider`
              ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если MIGX-TV для слайдера находятся на главной, то используй:

```
[[getImageList?
    &tvname=`sliderIm`
    &tpl=`slider`
    &docid=`1`
]]
```

в &docid=`ид ресурса`

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался, документация помогает)